# some php,sql,js mechanism

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i am trying to develop a small clinic management system but my problem is how the patient will be moving back and forth from registration consultation lab and bill.. moving the patient around different persons..doctor, nurse, registry... i am to use php, mysql and some js.. which i have good knowledge of but the way to tackle the above challenge is what i would be glad if you could give me an idea or if you have a sample or know where i can view that kind of mechanism... thanks

Comment: What do you mean "moving"? if you are referring to how to identity the person at each stage of the consultations (lab, dispenser, payment, etc.), try to add barcode scanner at each station for quick retrieve and access of patient's data. If this is not what you mean, please elaborate....

Comment: almost what you said,, but no barcode... like for example if the doctor sends the patient to the lab.. the lab attendant see which patient is coming through the system